# Converting HDF file (MODIS product) in ArcGIS as correctly georeferenced raster by ENVI?

Tags: modis, envi, hdf

Which algorithm I should use in ENVI 5.2 to open the MODIS product (MOD13Q1 or MODIS/Terra Vegetation Indices 16-Day L3 Global 250m Grid SIN V006), given as  HDF file to ArcGIS 10.5 as correctly  georeferenced raster showing the value of NDVI index?

The product is described here:
https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13q1_v006

I tried to do it by  ENVI 5.2. I opened it there (Open as - EO-1 - HDF4), but  when I exported it directly by operation “Send to ArcMap”, it was opened in ArcMap with incorrect projection. The same things happened when I imported this hdf file to ASCII and after that in ArcMap used the “ArcCII to Raster” Tool. The resulting raster has incorrect projection.
In the description of this product (by link above) says that it has Sinusoidal Coordinate system. So I suppose I should change it in the properties of file. However, I can’t change this coordinate system in the files, which I created by ENVI.
So, I need to know – which algorithm I should use in ENVI 5.2?

Answer (score 1):

After [MODIS Conversion Toolkit](https://github.com/dawhite/MCTK) installation you could use `Georeference MODIS` tool located in `/Geometric Correction/Georeference by Sensor/` which works well with `MOD02QKM`product (but not sure about `MOD13Q1`). After georeferencing - save output raster layer as tiff file and launch it with ArcGIS.

[image]